# Convert psycopg2 into asyncpg format. "syntax error at or near "%""

Tags: psycopg2, asyncpg

I'm converting a postgres script into asyncpg.

im getting "asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%""

i assume my placeholder format is incorrect but i cant find an example of a correct format.

Original working psycopg2 code:

```
async def commit_trade_postgres(response_data_input):
conn = await psycopg2.connect(
    "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password = 'postgres123' host='localhost' port= '5432'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trade_{symbol} (time timestamptz NOT NULL ,side text, size float, price float, tick_direction text)".format(**response_data_input))
conn.commit()
cur.execute(
    "SELECT create_hypertable('trade_{symbol}', 'time', if_not_exists => TRUE)".format(**response_data_input))
conn.commit()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO trade_{symbol} (time, side, size, price, tick_direction) VALUES (now(),  %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tick_direction)s)".format(
    **response_data_input), (response_data_input))
conn.commit()
print("commited trade")
```

My attempt as per the example code supplied int he docs:

```
async def commit_trade_postgres(response_data_input):
conn = await asyncpg.connect(database='postgres',  user='postgres',  password='postgres123',  host='localhost',  port='5432')
await conn.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trade_{symbol} (time timestamptz NOT NULL ,side text, size float, price float, tick_direction text)".format(**response_data_input))
await conn.execute(
    "SELECT create_hypertable('trade_{symbol}', 'time', if_not_exists => TRUE)".format(**response_data_input))
await conn.execute("INSERT INTO trade_{symbol} (time, side, size, price, tick_direction) VALUES (now(),  %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tick_direction)s)".format(
    **response_data_input), (response_data_input))
print("commited trade")
```

EDIT: Sample Query, Which i'm extracting 'data' as a dict.

```
response_dict_instrument = {'topic': 'instrument.BTCUSD', 'data': [{'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'mark_price': 12367.29, 'index_price': 12360.1}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're formatting query by yourself. You **never** should do that. Also I would suggest you to create table for every incoming symbol beforehand, do not do this dynamically.

Asyncpg template uses `$` sign with number to substitute values to query for you. [doc](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html)

So, syntax should be like this, if input is dictionary.

```py
async def save_input(input):
    # create connection
    conn = ...
    trade_symbol = input['symbol']
    query = "create table if not exists trade_{trade_symbol} ... ".format(trade_symbol=trade_symbol) # your column names go here
    await conn.execute(query)
    query = "SELECT create_hypertable('trade_{trade_symbol} ...".format(trade_symbol=trade_symbol)
    await conn.execute(query)

    # i'm not copyng your exact keys, you should do it yourself
    values = (input['key1'], input['key2'], input['key3'])
    query = "insert into trade_{trade_symbol} (key1, key2, key3) values ($1, $2, $3);".format(trade_symbol=trade_symbol)
    await conn.execute(query, *values)

    await conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, i've only been learning python a few weeks so the docs were a little confusing in regards to exact formatting. I didn't know that about formatting the query. With regards to "($1, $2, $3)", this was confusing me. If i'm using a DICT will it need to be formatted in the exact order as the sequence? i've added a sample of the DICt to the original question, does this mean i just need to rearrange the DICT?

Comment: You need to extract values from dict to list or tuple.

Comment: @ISpelGud I would also suggest you to store 'symbol' in column, and not create table for each one, that would simplify things.

Comment: for ``values = (input['key1'] ...etc`` is it possible to do this directly with a dict, or do you have to convert it to a list first?

Comment: @MjBVala you have to. You supply arguments for query as non-positional args. [doc](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html).